# Magit `zz` (stash both) does not allow whitespace in minibuffer

Tags: magit, minibuffer, whitespace

Sometimes when using command `zz` (stash both), the minibuffer to enter a stash message does not allow me to enter whitespace (e.g. space chars). I typically resolve to use dashes or underscores or even the tedious `C-q SPC`, since it is not really important. Yet on other occasions I am sure I have had no problems to enter space chars.

Can someone explain this? Is it a version problem, mine is 20221208.1848.

EDIT: this is embarrassing. The hints in comments and the answer about checking my setup and using `describe-key` in the minibuffer prompted me to inspect my startup script for emacs, grown over many years. It explicitly defines `(local-set-key " " 'minibuffer-complete-word)` for the minibuffer. Obviously I have no idea anymore when and why I had the bright idea to enter this.

I don't think this question can help others, as it is probably too specific to serve even as a hint to carefully check startup scripts and try a clean version first. So I will delete it some time soon, giving the contributors time to have a good laugh at my blunder.

Comment: I guess that's either a bug in this specific version of magit or a problem with your configuration. I can't reproduce this on a fresh installation with the latest Magit (20230131.1151).

Comment: Notwithstanding that this shouldn't be happening, you may find `M-SPC` slightly less tedious than `C-q SPC` on such occasions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as it describes a problem unique to the poster's configuration that has no general relevance to Emacs users.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs minibuffers for completion, except file-name completion, bind `SPC` to `minibuffer-complete-word`. I'm *guessing* that's the problem here.

Try either (1) globally binding `SPC` to `self-insert-command` in, say `minibuffer-local-completion-map` or (2) doing that only for the `zz` command.  Here's #1:

```lisp
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "SPC") 'self-insert-command)
```

If you want `SPC` to self-insert only for must-match completion then do that for `minibuffer-local-must-match-map` instead.

---

If, as a comment by @Gilles guesses, the command in question uses a keymap other than a completion keymap -- e.g., if it uses just function `read-from-minibuffer`, which uses keymap `minibuffer-local-map`, then just do the same thing I showed above, but with that keymap.

But first, check what the binding of `SPC` is in that keymap. You can do that with command `describe-keymap`. If that command is not available in your version of Emacs, you can get it with library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el).

Comment: I wouldn't expect completion for the stash message, and the latest version of Magit calls `read-from-minibuffer`, not `completing-read`. I haven't checked the version of Magit in the question which is very slightly older.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': In that case, what's the keymap used in that call, and what's the binding of `SPC` in it? If it's the usual `minibuffer-local-map`, and if the binding is not `self-insert-command`, then something (Magit?) must have changed the binding there. In any case, whatever the keymap used, the solution is the same: bind `SPC` to `self-insert-command`, if self-inserting is what's wanted. Oh, and why the downvote?

Comment: In the current version, the `keymap` argument to `read-from-minibuffer` is `nil`, thus it uses `minibuffer-local-map` where SPC is not bound (and thus defaults to its global binding which is `self-insert-command`). Changing `minibuffer-local-map` or `minibuffer-local-completion-map` would not help (in the first case it's the default setting, in the second case it's not supposed to be used).

Comment: @Gilles: So you're saying that using `SPC` in the minibuffer does not insert a space char, even though its binding in the minibuffer (here) is `self-insert-command`? How do you explain that description?

Comment: No, on my machine (both with a fresh install with the latest Magit, and with my normal installation that I haven't updated in a long time), SPC at the `magit-stash-both` “Stash message: ” prompt inserts a space as expected.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': I was talking about OP's report. My answer was to what OP described. IOW, IF that's what's seen THEN check the keymap and binding in it, and change the binding to `self-insert-command`.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvotes?